# Equivalence of class reluctanct and simple class regular expression

Tags: java, regex

This is a question just to satisfy my curiosity.  Consider the following two Java regular expressions: `[, !.]` and `[, !.]+?`.  Are they equivalent? I have tried to come up with examples where they wouldn't be equivalent, but I cannot find one.

EDIT:
I understand that for the sake of matching an entire String they are not equivalent.  But when you use them to find multiple matches of substrings within a string, they seem equivalent to me.

Comment: No, I meant those up there. I just edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: As it is, they are equivalent in term of what they will match in a `find` operation. They won't when you add more stuffs after them, or use them in a `fullmatch` operation

Comment: They are not the equivalent are they?

Comment: Is my edit correct? Or is it that they are also equivalent when matching an entire string?

Comment: Yes, for matching an entire string they would not be equivalent, since the first would only match a 1-character string while the other one could also match longer strings provided they only contain the characters in the class. For `String.matches()` and the like think of the expression as being surrounded by `^` and `$`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a self-contained example within the same `String`, for your character class matched greedily, reluctantly, or with no quantifier.

```
Pattern greedy = Pattern.compile("[, !.]+");
Pattern reluctant = Pattern.compile("[, !.]+?");
Pattern nonQuantified = Pattern.compile("[, !.]");
String example = "foo !! bar";
Matcher greedyMatcher = greedy.matcher(example);
Matcher reluctantMatcher = reluctant.matcher(example);
Matcher nonQMatcher = nonQuantified.matcher(example);
while (greedyMatcher.find()) {
    System.out.printf("Greedy found: %s%n", greedyMatcher.group());
}
while (reluctantMatcher.find()) {
    System.out.printf("Reluctant found: %s%n", reluctantMatcher.group());
}
while (nonQMatcher.find()) {
    System.out.printf("Non-quantified found: %s%n", nonQMatcher.group());
}
```

**Output**

```
Greedy found:  !! 
Reluctant found:  
Reluctant found: !
Reluctant found: !
Reluctant found:  
Non-quantified found:  
Non-quantified found: !
Non-quantified found: !
Non-quantified found:
```

**Explanation**

- Greedy will match as much as possible. Therefore, `find` returns `true` once and `group()` coagulates the whole match
- Reluctant will match as little as possible. Therefore, `find` returns `true` once per match in the "example" `String`, and `group`, invoked 4 times, returns one space, one `!`, another `!` and a last space
- Non-quantified will match only one character each invocation, hence works like the reluctant quantifier in this instance
- [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html)'s the official documentation on quantifiers
- [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)'s the official API on Java `Pattern`, useful for quantifier syntax

**Note**

- As pointed out, your question displays two character classes, but the first is not quantified.
- I went on and assumed you meant to quantify it as greedy, hence the `[, !.]+` in my example, instead of non-quantified `[, !.]` in your question

Comment: The question is about `[, !.]+?` and `[, !.]`, not `[, !.]+`.

Comment: @Kobi the question is about greedy vs reluctant. `[, !.]` is not quantified, therefore applies to neither.

Comment: The question isn't about greedy vs reluctant, though the title is misleading.

Comment: @Kobi it's actually ambiguous so I edited my answer by stating `[, !.]` is not quantified.

Answer (score 2):

They are equivalent when you use them **as is** with `Matcher.find()`.

`[, !.]+?`, after matching the required one repetition, will try the sequel (in this case, it is the end of the pattern, so it's an *accept* node), and return the single character match.

Therefore, it ends up logically the same as `[, !.]`, when used with `Matcher.find()`.

Due to the laziness of the quantifier, more repetitions are only tried when the sequel fails, and that would be the case if you add something else after it, or use the regex with `Matcher.matches()` (which only accepts the match when you reach the end of the string).